# Trying to delete array pointer with empty address (not NULL) in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I created a class that contains an array of pixel intensity values. When this class is copied, I receive an error as if I am trying to delete a non-assigned array. Since I'm pretty sure I'm not setting the pointed address of the pointer to anything between creation and copy of the class, it is all so mysterious to me how the pointer's address is anything different than NULL. How can I check for empty pointed address?

`data_ == reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>("")`

Does not work.

**The class:**

```
template<class T> class PixelArray {
public:
    int width_, height_;
    int size_;
    T* data_;

    PixelArray() {
        data_ = NULL;
    };

    ~PixelArray() {
        if (data_ != NULL)
            delete[] data_;
        data_ = NULL;
    };

    PixelArray(const PixelArray& other)
    {
        if (data_)
            delete[] data_;  // ERROR BEING THROWN HERE

        data_ = NULL:
        data_ = new T[other.size_];
        size_ = other.size_;
        width_ = other.width_;
        height_ = other.height_;
        std::copy(other.data_, other.data_ + other.size_, data_);
    }        
};
```

**The problem:**

[**Status of the variable at the time of breaking**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30ONr.png)

Comment: Why not use unique_ptr?

Comment: You're treating copy construction as if there is "there" there. There isn't yet.

Comment: Why you're not using `std::vector<T> data_;` for this is a mystery. nearly all of this code disappears if you do so.

Comment: Because in other parts of the code I iterate through the array with four pointers upping their pointed address by one every cycle of a loop. But I guess that could be done with vector iterators if it doesn't reduce performance (performance is important in this case).

Comment: The performance would be similar, if not identical, and I can only imagine how much it would simplify the rest of your code. A vector is nothing more than a dynamic contiguous sequence of objects, which is exactly what your `data_` is intended to be. [Don't let pointers own resources](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1) if you can at-all avoid it (and most of the time, you can).

Comment: This isn't the problem, but that destructor does a lot of wheel-spinning. There's no need to test for `NULL`; `delete[] data_;` works just fine if `data_` is `NULL`. And setting `data_` to `NULL` after the delete is pointless: the object is going away, and nobody will ever see `data_` again. The body of the destructor should just be `delete[] data_;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the copy-constructor the member variables have not been initialized yet, there is nothing to `delete[]`.

Instead the member variable `data_` will haven an *indeterminate* value, and it will be seemingly random and most likely not equal to a null pointer, which means you will have *undefined behavior*.

The simplest solution? Don't `delete[]` using the uninitialized pointer.

---

The copy-constructor is just like any other constructor, it's called when an instance is created. No other constructor will be called for copy-construction, only the copy-constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (data_)
        delete[] data_;  // ERROR BEING THROWN HERE
```

data hasn't been initialized yet, you're in the copy constructor; the default constructor isn't called for you.

Deleting these 2 lines will remove your access to uninitialized variables and resolve your problem.

As Marcos said in the comments - you could resolve the issue better by using a smart pointer

Comment: Will I not invite a memory leak in case I am copying to an initialized object of this class by deleting those two lines, though?

Comment: A memory leak occurs when you do not free memory that you've allocated.  You haven't allocated any memory to data at that point (you're in the constructor!!) so no, you won't get a memory leak

Comment: As a side note, having the raw pointer like that publicly exposed isn't very nice... it invites a whole host of problems.

Comment: So using a unique or smart pointer would be the ultimate solution to all my sorrows?

Comment: @GavinLock I think you're confused, please re-read my answer.

Comment: @hhhhhhhhh A unique ptr is a smart pointer; A smart pointer is basically something that deals with calling delete when it's required, so that you don't have to worry about it.  More information about it can be viewed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: @hhhhhhhhh - the function in question is a "copy constructor". It can only copy to a new object, never to " an initialized object of this class". Copying to an existing object is the job of an "assignment operator"

Comment: @UKMonkey - sorry, my comment was supposed to be addressed to the OP (it was a response to his first comment to your answer). Somewhere between my eyes and my fingers, my brain went on holiday.

Answer (score 2):

> Trying to delete array pointer with empty address (not NULL)

There is no such thing. There is the null pointer (value 0), and there are non-null values for pointers. The non-null pointers may or may not point to a valid object. Perhaps by "empty" you mean that the pointed object is not valid.

> How can I check for empty pointed address?

There is no way to check whether the pointed object is valid. You must make sure that the pointer always points to a valid object as long as you use it.

---

There are only 2 cases where it is OK to call `delete[]` on a pointer:

- It is null
- The pointer was returned by `new[]` and the pointer has not been deleted previously.

Deleting the pointer in every other case causes UB. Cases where a pointer does not meet those requirements:

- The pointer was never initialized. Example:

  ```
  T* data_;
  ```
- The pointer was initialized to a value that was not returned by `new[]`. Examples:

  ```
  T* data_ = new T;
  T* data_ = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>("");
  ```
- The pointer was returned by `new[]` but has been deleted previously. This is called a dangling pointer.

  ```
  T* data_ = new T[10];
  delete[] data_;
  // data_ is a danging pointer here
  ```

---

```
PixelArray(const PixelArray& other)
{
    if (data_)
        delete[] data_;  // ERROR BEING THROWN HERE
```

> it is all so mysterious to me how the pointer's address is anything different than NULL

The pointer hasn't been initialized, so its value is unspecified. It would be NULL only if you had initialized or assigned it to NULL.

You're deleting an uninitialized pointer, hence the program has undefined behaviour.

PS. It is redundant to check whether `data_` is not null, since it is safe to delete a null pointer.

---

Soution to the immediate problem: Do not try to delete the uninitialized pointer - remove the first two lines of the copy constructor. Solution to further problems: Use `std::vector`. This will fix your bugs and greatly simplify the code.

> [I don't use `std::vector`] Because in other parts of the code I iterate through the array with four pointers upping their pointed address by one every cycle of a loop.

`std::vector` does not prevent you from doing that.

> But I guess that could be done with vector iterators if it doesn't reduce performance (performance is important in this case).

It could be done with iterators as well, and I know of no technical reason why they would be any less performant than pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete[] data_ in the copy constructor because, data_ has not been allocated yet.

I think what you are trying to achieve with delete[] data should be done in an assignment operator function.

```
PointerArray& operator=(const PointerArray& other) {
    if (data_){delete[] data_;}
    //allocate data_ and copy the contents from other.data_
    //rest of the assignment code here
}
```